# My ZVS circuit is not oscillating

Tags: high-voltage, induction

I had made mini ZVS driver for generating plasma arcs. When is tested ZVS driver with a pair of LEDs then it worked fine, one LED lights up and switches if I connect negative wire to cathode of other LED means ZVS driver is working well. As well as transformer is also fine which is a CCFL transformer from laptop backlight inverter board. But when I connect ZVS driver to transformer, also connecting inductor at centre tap, then there is no output voltage at secondary, I think circuit was not oscillating. And when circuit is switched on then LED that is used as an indicator blinks and immediately turns off or gets too dim as it is seemingly off. Where is the problem? I had also used circuit simulator application to find out what is happening but was not able to set values for MOSFETs and transformer, got more confused.

These are values of components that I have used:-
Inductor:- 4.7uH,
Capacitor:- 1uF,
MOSFETS:- 25V ,75A, 5m ohm,
Resistors:- 333 ohm,
DIODES:- PH4148,
SMD LED green,
CCFL transformer,
5V-9V battery (used in radio transmitters),[image]

Comment: No, I had used circuit simulator but I don't understand what is happening, moreover, I was not able to set values for MOSFET and transformer

Comment: Applications can't create situations same as reality

Comment: Leaving MOSFETs and transformer I had set values for all other components but in that application circuit was working but in reality it's not